# Mailserver, outgoing mails are not delivered

Tags: email-server

I have a private root server and use it, among other things, as a mail server. I use a Lotus Domino Server for it (I am or was a Notes Developer)

In the last weeks I get reports that my outgoing mails are not received, some work, some not. There seems to be a problem with GMX.
Not one of my configs changed. The only thing that happened was that my server was restarted by the provider during a maintenance period a few months ago, but everything restarted automatically via scripts. The server is Linux based and has a static IP adress, also I am using my own domain.

I don't receive any error messages, except one time, I received a fault report that a mail couldn't be delivered, but that was only one time. It said "Router: Failed to connect to SMTP host GMX.DE because : SMTP Protocol Returned a Permanent Error"
Nothing more, Didn't found any more clues in my logs.

I don't ask for advice with the config of my server, the config did run fine for several years now. So I think there must be something else. I already checked http://www.dnsbl.info/ and http://mxtoolbox.com/ for ip and domain but all sites report an ok, I don't seem to be blacklisted, which would have been the most obvious solution. Also my mails don't seem to be delivered to the spam folder, I already checked that.

Do you have any idea what I could do or check to find out what's wrong right now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do the mail logs say?

Comment: (Also, what is a "private root server"? I am not familiar with this term.)

Comment: @JennyD  In Germany, non-managed servers (and sometimes VPS as well) are marketed as *root server*, as you have root access to the OS, as opposed to shared hosting.  I am not sure what is meant by the *private* classification though but it could mean a dedicated machine, not a VPS.

Comment: Yes, this server is a non virtual machine and I have root acced to the OS. It is rented by http://www.euserv.com/de/ By private I meant that it is only used for private purpose by myself, so no corporate related things or such.

Answer (score 0):

> SMTP Protocol Returned a Permanent Error

Must be followed by a 5.XXX.XXX error code.

According with [RFC3463](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3463):

```
      5.XXX.XXX   Permanent Failure

         A permanent failure is one which is not likely to be resolved
         by resending the message in the current form.  Some change to
         the message or the destination must be made for successful
         delivery.

   A client must recognize and report class sub-code even where
   subsequent subject sub-codes are unrecognized.
```

Get the error code, it will give you the failure root cause.

Comment: @MatthiasNicklisch Please include the log message in the question. Click "edit" below the question.

Comment: The only other error message I found in the logs is this one:
01/26/2016 15:44:25 HTTP JVM: 15:44:26.140 ERROR: [PacketDispatcher.cpp:95] Run: Exception in connection: TransportException [510/202] handshake error, 'JDWP-Handshake' is not received
Unfortunately no other error message and it alsoy displays no error code.. the log from the notes server is indeed not the best one =)